# SQL Server SELECT statement for entire rows given a specific entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with a statement which allow me to view all the data based on a given artists in a my playlist database.

example, I have a artists, led zep, with two songs, and another artists with one, I want to be able to call led zep, and be able to view all tracks by them, also artists name is a text, so it the song name.

id is primary key, album is text, artists is text, name is text, rating is int, I want to be able to call upon all songs buy a given artists.

these are some statements I tried.

```
SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE Artist = led zep

SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE Artist = 'led zep'

SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE Artist = "led zep"
```

none work any help would be greatly appreciated. If you havenet noticed by new I'm very new to SQL server.

thanks for the replies, and no the way i wrote it up probably got people confused, the artists is in caps in my database along with all other headings.

The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. i get this error on the second statement by the way.

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: When you mean all songs, you mean you only want the song names? Because the second statement should be working

Comment: And the next "unable to compare strings" post. Hint: WHERE Artist and field "artists is text" in your post - they are spelled different. I am sure SQL Server tells you this (filed not found or something like that) and you just prefer to not read the error message ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, the column name is **artists**

```
SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE artists = 'led zep'
```

Answer (score 1):

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to
>   operator.

Why did you choose the text datatype for the Artist column?? It makes no sense; text was used for LOBs and is deprecated btw. As a general rule, don't use it.

Please change your table schema so that the Artist column is nvarchar of proper length. Your second statement will work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `LIKE` operator, incase you are not sure about the exact string value.

```
SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE Artist like '%led zep%'
```